# Shortest knight path

Tags: c++, c++14, pathfinding, rags-to-riches

In preparing a review of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119874/finding-smallest-number-of-moves/119883#119883), I decided to rewrite the code from scratch using a more object oriented approach as I suggested in my review.

To recapitulate the problem statement, we are given an input such as the following:

```
6 5
. s . . .
. d . . .
. . x . .
. . x . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
```

The two integers are the number of rows and columns respectively, and the lines that follow are the board to be examined.  A [knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_%28chess%29) is placed at starting point `s` and must travel to the destination at `d` without landing on any occupied squares (denoted by `x`).  Open squares are marked with `.` and whitespace must separate each square in the input.

The output of the program is the minimum number of valid knight moves to get from `s` to `d` or the word `"NO"` if there is no path.  The search uses a simple breadth first search.  Each call to `validMoves` generates a `std::vector` of all unvisited squares that can be reached with one move of a knight originating on any of the squares indicated in the input `std::vector` `moves`.

The algorithm terminates when either there are no valid moves left or a path has been found to the destination.

I'm interested in a general review, but in particular, the repeated calls to `tryMove()` seem somewhat inelegant to me, but I didn't come up with anything that I thought was better.

### knight.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

class Board
{
public:
    Board(int n, int m) : 
        start{ERR},
        finish{ERR},
        rows{n},
        cols{m},
        map{new char[rows*cols]}
    {}
    virtual ~Board() { delete[] map; }
    int mindistance() const {
        if (finish == ERR || start == ERR) {
            return ERR;
        }
        return measure(start, finish);
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Board &b) {
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = b.rows; i; --i) {
            for (int j = b.cols; j; --j, ++a) {
                in >> b.map[a];
                switch(b.map[a]) {
                    case STARTCHAR:
                        if (b.start != ERR) {
                            throw std::runtime_error("Duplicate start character detected");
                        }
                        b.start = a;
                        break;
                    case ENDCHAR:
                        if (b.finish != ERR) {
                            throw std::runtime_error("Duplicate finish character detected");
                        }
                        b.finish = a;
                        break;
                    case BLOCKEDCHAR:
                    case OPENCHAR:
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw std::runtime_error("Unknown character detected");
                }
            }
        }
        return in;
    }
    static constexpr char STARTCHAR = 's';
    static constexpr char ENDCHAR = 'd';
    static constexpr char BLOCKEDCHAR = 'x';
    static constexpr char OPENCHAR = '.';
    static constexpr int ERR = -1;
private:
    int measure(int here, int there) const {
        std::vector<bool> visited(cols * rows, false);
        int distance = 0;
        for (std::vector<int> moves{here}; moves.size(); moves = validMoves(visited, moves)) {
            if (moves.end() != std::find(moves.begin(), moves.end(), there)) {
                return distance;
            }
            ++distance;
        } 
        return ERR;
    }
    void tryMove(int x, int y, std::vector<bool>& visited, std::vector<int>& result) const { 
        if (isValid(x, y)) { 
            int a=addr(x, y); 
            if (!visited[a]) { 
                visited[a] == true; 
                result.push_back(a); 
            }
        }
    }
    std::vector<int> validMoves(std::vector<bool>& visited, std::vector<int>& moves) const {
        std::vector<int> result;
        // create a vector of all possible moves
        for (auto m : moves) {
            int x = getX(m);
            int y = getY(m);
            visited[m] = true;
            // eight possible moves
            tryMove(x+1, y+2, visited, result);
            tryMove(x+1, y-2, visited, result);
            tryMove(x-1, y+2, visited, result);
            tryMove(x-1, y-2, visited, result);
            tryMove(x+2, y+1, visited, result);
            tryMove(x+2, y-1, visited, result);
            tryMove(x-2, y+1, visited, result);
            tryMove(x-2, y-1, visited, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
    int addr(int x, int y) const {
        return x + y * cols;
    }
    int getX(int here) const {
        return here % cols;
    }
    int getY(int here) const {
        return here / cols;
    }
    bool isValid(int x, int y) const {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= cols || y >= rows) 
            return false;
        return (map[addr(x, y)] != BLOCKEDCHAR);
    }

/* for 4 row x 5 col matrix, we have:
 *
 *  0  1  2  3  4
 *  5  6  7  8  9
 * 10 11 12 13 14
 * 15 16 17 18 19
 *
 * so getX(11) = 1 and getY(11) = 2
 * and getX(4) = 4 and getY(4) = 0
 * and getX(17) = 2 and getY(17) = 3
 */
    int start;
    int finish;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    char *map;
};


int main()
{
    int n, m; 
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    Board board(n, m);
    try {
        std::cin >> board;
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << ": Terminating program\n";
        return 1;
    }
    int distance = board.mindistance();
    if (distance == Board::ERR) {
        std::cout << "NO\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << distance << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: How was the performance and memory usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A standard way to loop over a regular set of moves is to prepare an array of deltas:

  ```
      using square = std::pair<int, int>;
      std::vector<square> deltas = {
          {1, 2}, {1, -2}, {-1, 2}, {-1, -2},
          {2, 1}, {2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-2, -1}
      };


      for (auto delta: deltas) {
          tryMove(x + delta.first, y + delta.second);
      }
  ```
- It feels that `std::pair<int, int>` generally represents a square better than a single integer.

Comment: Well, a `const static square deltas[]` would be simpler and possibly more efficient...